CodeGen graphql returns type unkown
Here is my codeGen file
const config: CodegenConfig = {
  schema: "http://localhost:3000/graphql",
  documents: ["core/shared/gql/**/*.ts"],
  // ignoreNoDocuments: true, // for better experience with the watcher
  generates: {
    "./core/utils/generator/": {
      preset: "client",
    },
  },
};

Here is my operation
export const createsManyAnswer = graphql(`
  mutation (
    $answerinput: [AnswerInput!]!
  ) {
    createsManyAnswer(
      createAnswerInput: { Answers: $answerinput }
    ) {
      Assessment
    }
  }
`);

Here is the code generator graphql output:
export function graphql(source: string): unknown;

export function graphql(source: string) {
  return (documents as any)[source] ?? {};
}

I've already double checked that the document paths are referenced correctly. I've already checked similar previous post but none of them solve my problem

It's so dumb but the solution is to always set names to the operations. In my case I needed to add a name for the mutation operation.
Otherwise the code gen skip those operations! It must be documented somewhere!
export const createsManyAnswer = graphql(`
  mutation CreatesManyAnswer(
    $answerinput: [AnswerInput!]!
  ) {
    createsManyAnswer(
      createAnswerInput: { Answers: $answerinput }
    ) {
      Assessment
    }
  }
`);

